# How to inspect object declared within a "with"?

Tags: vb.net, debugging

In VB I can write this:

```
Dim x As MyObj = New MyObj()
x.First = 1
x.Run
```

like this:

```
With New MyObj()
    .First = 1
    .Run
End
```

which I find much cleaner.  one problem I have is that whilst debugging, the first form allows me to inspect the object whereas the second does not.  Or does it?  how do I do it?

thanks - ekkis

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Autos" window, available under the "Debug > Windows" menu.

Comment: no.  that window doesn't show an object that represents the object `With` is working with

Comment: @ekkis -- I'm sorry you aren't able to get it working, but you are not correct.  I use that window all the time just for that reason.

Comment: hmm... I'm running VS13 and I do see various items in that window but clearly none of them are what the `With` would be working with